# React Cloudinary Image Transformation Exception

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I'm building a React website using Cloudinary and am having an issue trying to use `Transformations`.

Here's my JSX:

```
<Image cloudName={'my-cloud-name'} publicId={'my-image.jpg'}>
  <Transformation width={400} height={300}/>
</Image>
```

Without the `Transformation` tag the image renders, but with the `Transformation` tag in I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mapped.filter is not a function
at Image.getChildTransformations (CloudinaryComponent.js:74)
at Image.getTransformation (CloudinaryComponent.js:93)
at Image.getUrl (CloudinaryComponent.js:121)
at Image.prepareState (Image.js:93)
at new Image (Image.js:55)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (common.js:10034)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (common.js:17264)
at Object.mountComponent (common.js:18081) 
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (common.js:16701) 
at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (common.js:11459)
```

I've found no evidence of anyone else having this issue through googling, and I've tried several different examples but still have had no luck.

Thanks!

Note: I'm using `cloudinary-react@1.0.4`

Comment: Hey @harold, did you wrap it like so:


```js
  <CloudinaryContext cloudName="my-cloud-name">
                    <Image publicId="my-image.jpg">
                         <Transformation width={400} height={300}/>
                    </Image>
 </CloudinaryContext>
```

Comment: I've tried that previously to no joy, but maybe I was mistaken. I'll give this another go and report back